# Rerouting bathroom vent

Tags: plumbing

My vent is interfering with the installation of a recessed medicine cabinet.  Can I make two turns so I just move over less than a foot?

Comment: Not enough info, please include a detailed description.  What kind of vent ?

Comment: Need to know size of ducting, output of fan, total duct run length, number of elbows in total run, and proximity of initial elbows to fan motor.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate unless OP is installing a medicine cabinet in his ceiling, it seems more likely he is referring to drain line vents than exhaust fan duct work.

Comment: @CactusCake -- I guess I should learn to read! I'd delete my question, but don't mind being reminded... To everyone else, please ignore my ramblings.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of IPC chapter 9, you can add turns as long as the horizontal part of the run slopes towards the drain at least 2% (1/4" per foot).  That's so if water gets into the vent it will flow down the drain by gravity and not pool up in your vent system.  Another stipulation would be you need to have at least 6" vertical rise above the flood level rim of the highest trap or trapped fixture being vented before going horizontal.  (horizontal being considered anything less than 45 degree slope)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a plumber but, considering freshop's note about horizontal runs needing slope of 1/4" per foot, I might suggest making your offset with two 45s on either end. IOW, consider your vertical vent. You apparently want to route around something (a new medicine cabinet). Cut the vent below where the cabinet will go. Add a 45 degree fitting (directing the vent to the right, for example). Add a section of pipe long enough to clear the desired area. Add another 45 degree fitting such the opening is straight up. Add a section of pipe (vertically) long enough to clear the desired area. Add a 45 degree fitting (directing the vent to the left, for example). Add a section of pipe long enough to get back close to the top part of the vent line. Connect with a 45 degree fitting. This way avoid any issues with sloping a horizontal section correctly.

Here is an image shows an offset created as I describe above (except that it does not offset back and connect along the same vertical axis).

[image]